# Same SQL Server scalar function runs 4x faster within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I'm aware that SQL Server has issues with running user-defined functions over large rowsets. But my problem is a little bit different.

I have a test code like:

```
SELECT TESTNAME = TESTFUNC() 
INTO #TEMPTABLE 
FROM SOMETABLE
```

`TESTFUNC` has no code in it. Just returns 1 for testing purposes.

When I run this, it takes >= 24 seconds for 1.5 million rows.

If I put the same code inside a stored procedure and execute it with the same user and everything, it takes ~ 6 seconds.

The query time stats in the execution plan for the plans linked below are

[image]

vs

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TESTPROC AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TESTNAME = TESTFUNC() 
    INTO #TEMPTABLE 
    FROM SOMETABLE 
END
```

Estimated and actual execution plans are the same for both but "Compute Scalar" step takes a lot longer when the statement is called directly.

What makes the difference?

Edit: Actual execution plans

[image: Slow Scalar]

[image: Fast Scalar]

[image: Slow-2]

[image: Fast-2]

Edit 2: Function definition

```
CREATE FUNCTION TESTFUNC
(
)
RETURNS BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN 1
END
```

Plans:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy0gFh53F

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1Dfi352F

Comment: That doesn't repro.  Look at the Actual Execution plan, it will contain CPU and Wait stats that should explain the difference in duration.

Comment: Note that it is specifically **multi-line** user functions that have a reputation of running slow (especially mlTVFs). Well written inline user defined functions (iTVF's have been supported since SQL Server 2000, and inlining of scalar functions since SQL Server 2019) can perform very well, even with very large data sets.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Added screens for actual executions. Any insights?

Comment: Please post the XML for the plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Also include the function definition in the question

Comment: @MartinSmith added plans and function definition

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't trying against a global temp table. Will try that and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Case reproduces for me with both local and global temp tables

Comment: How many CPU's?

Comment: @Arvo 46 processors

Comment: If you use maxdop hints to limit CPU count, does something cahnge? Query plan doesn't show parallelism, but it could be possible that some calculations are pushed to multiple CPUs (I can be mistaken of course).

Comment: @Arvo - referencing a non inlined scalar UDF means it definitely will be serial

Comment: Still doesn't repro for me on my SQL Server 2016 but I only have localdb installed and a much earlier build than yours (you are on SP2 - CU17)

Comment: This wasn't happening on our server either until a month ago. It became a problem overnight and DBA team is pretty sure nothing has changed on the server. We're trying to understand what might have "not" been changed :)

Comment: If you add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to the UDF do you still get the same behaviour? This often fixes UDF ills when they don't access any data

Comment: with schemabinding, both versions run <1 seconds. what if UDF accesses data?

Comment: I'd try putting the logic into an inline table valued function if possible. But this still doesn't explain why the difference in behaviour. If I *was* able to reproduce it in a dev environment I'd likely use a profiler tool (such as Windows Performance Recorder) to see what the busier code paths are in the slow case.

Comment: We can work it around using stored procedures for routine work. But it makes debugging or running manual checks a real pain. And SCHEMABINDING doesn't work with functions accessing data as expected...